# Find out why queryCommandEnabled returns false

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, clipboard

I am trying to copy content to clipboard using JS in an angular app.

Unfortunately, `document.queryCommandEnabled("copy")` will consistently return `false`. Is there any way to understand why the browser denies the command to be executed? What are the criterion to enable the command?

Code:

```
function copyText(text) {
    var input = document.createElement('textarea');
    document.body.appendChild(input);
    input.value = text;
    input.focus();
    input.select();
    var success = document.execCommand('Copy');
    input.remove();
    return success;
}
```

I test if the command is enabled before I run this function:

```
if(document.queryCommandEnabled("copy")) // Always return false
    executeCopy(text_value);
```

Comment: Have you tried running `document.queryCommandSupported()` to check if the `'copy'` command is even supported? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/queryCommandSupported

Answer (score 2):

The document.queryCommandEnabled ("copy") command returns true when there is a selection otherwise it will return false

```js
function doCopy(){
  if(document.queryCommandEnabled("copy")){
    copyText("Hola")
  }else{
    alert("Never Fired");
  }
}

function copyText(text) {
    var input = document.createElement('textarea');
    document.body.appendChild(input);
    input.value = text;
    input.focus();
    input.select();
    var success = document.execCommand('Copy');
    input.remove();
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
  <input type="button" onclick="doCopy('Herman')" value="s">
  </body>
</html>
```

we must make a selection so that it works correctly

```js
function copyText(text) {
    var input = document.createElement('textarea');
    document.body.appendChild(input);
    input.value = text;
    input.focus();
    input.select();
    if(document.queryCommandEnabled("copy")){
        var success = document.execCommand('Copy');
        input.remove();
        alert("Copy Ok");
    }else{
        alert("queryCommandEnabled is false");
    }
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
  <input type="button" onclick="copyText('Herman')" value="s">
  </body>
</html>
```

according to **Blundering Philosopher's** comment, use *document.queryCommandSupported(command)*; to validate if the command is possible to run in the browser instance

```js
function doCopy(){
  if(document.queryCommandSupported("copy")){
    copyText("Hello")
  }else{
    alert("Never Fired");
  }
}

function copyText(text) {
    var input = document.createElement('textarea');
    document.body.appendChild(input);
    input.value = text;
    input.focus();
    input.select();
    var success = document.execCommand('Copy');
    input.remove();
    alert("Copy Ok");
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <input type="button" value="Copy" onclick="doCopy()">
  </body>
</html>
```